# Adding new custom Permissions in Drupal tutorial

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I created module now i want to set permission on that module so some of the users can see that field. I searched on google and stackoverflow but I didn't get proper answer as i needed.
My code as below

```
function downloaded_menu() {
     $items['user/%user/downloaded_poems'] = array(
    'title' => 'Downloaded Poems',
    'page callback' => 'downloaded_content_page',
    'access arguments' => array('poet downloaded work'),    
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 11,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Now I want to give permission to particular user. who can only see.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to use [hook_permission](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) to do so.

Code example:

```
function downloaded_permission()
{
    return array(
        'poet downloaded work' => array(
            'title' => t('poet downloaded work'), // the title to be shown in the permissions page
            'description' => t('poet downloaded work'), // the description to be shown in the permissions page
            'restrict access' => FALSE,
        ),
    );
}
```

Then go to the permissions page and give the permissions to the required roles.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.